# Read sensors from different roscores

Tags: ros, subscribe, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bunch of robots with a separate roscore running on each of them. Now I would like to connect from a C++ application to every robot and read its sensor values. I saw the rosmultimaster package which seems to provide a python API to do exactly what I want. But is there also a way to connect to more than one core at once with the C++ API?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9891/read-sensors-from-different-roscores./) by [Daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/496/daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-05-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could relay some topics from one master to another master. A tool for doing that is somewhere in the WG repostiory:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/multimaster_experimental/trunk/foreign_relay

For instance, if you have one robot with master uri A and another one with master uri B, you can set up the relay by running the following command on A:

```
rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay adv http://B:11311 /a/laser /laser
```

It will basically advertise the topic /a/laser on B.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/496/daniel/) on 2011-05-05**:
It is not really what I had in mind, but I will give it a try. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Daniel,

do you really need to run a different core for each robot or could you move toward one unique roscore running through your system of different machines?

The later solution is very easy to implement as the only step needed is seting the system variables ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI on all your machines without having to modify any code. Check that [page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) for more info.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/496/daniel/) on 2011-05-04**:
Hey Raph, thanks for your answer.

I already thought about this. Unfortunately all robots should work autonomously and they are just linked with a very unstable wireless LAN connection which often breaks. So its not really an option to use a single core.

Daniel